# How to remove zero values from a cell array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array, zero

I have a cell array in MATLAB which looks like this,

```
arr=  4  5  8
     22 23  0
```

Zero values always appear at the end of the last row. If there are two zero values it will look like this,

```
arr=  4  5  8
     22  0  0
```

There is no row contains zeros for its all positions. Could anyone help me to remove those zero values exists in the last row? What I want is something like this

```
arr=  4   5   8
     22  23
```

Comment: Do you want `[ ]` in place of zeros? There has to be something. You can't have `arr= {4  5  8;  22 23}`

Comment: Not possible unless you have a place holder in each cell. MATLAB does not support ragged matrices.

Comment: @SardarUsama yup.. I want [ ] in those places. Since I have a lot of cell arrays like that, I want an efficient way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have scalars at every index of the cell array then convert `arr` to a matrix, find the indices where zeros are present and then replace them with `[]`.

```
arr([arr{:}]==0)={[]};
```

Comment: or `arr(cell2mat(arr)==0)={[]}`